# How to find Delta of a column in apache spark using SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
C_ID| Month  |Usage
------------------
1   |January | 10 
2   |February|100
1   |March   | 20
2   |April   | 40
1   |June    | 50
```

I am required to find a delta (difference) of Usage values. Condition is, for each C_ID I have to loop over each month, and find difference of usage values of the present row/month with the previous.

The resultant will look like follows:

```
C_ID| Month  |Usage| Delta
--------------------------
1   |January | 10  |  0    // Since there is nothing before January so 0
2   |February|100  |  0    // Similar as above
1   |March   | 20  | 10
2   |April   | 40  | -60
1   |June    | 50  | 30
```

What is coming to my mind is group by C_ID first. But how will I keep on finding differences?

Any help will be appreciated.

Much thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: In the linked example, the OP didn't seem to care about the order of the rows after all the transformations have occurred, so the output was sorted by date. It's not immediately obvious to me how to preserve the strange interleaving order of the rows here?